# how does one Indent the body text of a latex document, but not sections?

Tags: latex

For accessibility reasons, I would like to indent the body text of my document, but not the sections. How would I go about doing this?

I would like the result to be:

```
Chapter 1.

Section 1.1

    Some body text here
    Some more body text

Section 1.2

    Some more body text...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/sectsty.html) and [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/geometry.html) packages.  You can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\hspace*{-3cm}}
\usepackage[left=5cm,textwidth=400pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Of course, you will need to change the lengths above to suit your needs.